# Is there a way to cache a self-hosted PostgreSQL db connection across Lambda invocations?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

We have a self-hosted (i.e. on top of EC2 instance) PostgreSQL instance, which we intent to access from a Step Functions, which invoke multiple Lambdas. I am aware that for the RDS instances there is an RDS Proxy service available which solves for this exact scenario. Given that our instance is self-hosted - is there a way to accomplish caching the database connection across multiple lambda invocations without having to re-establish it for each one?

Comment: Is your goal to avoid connection overhead for Lambda invocations (which would be accomplished by caching), or to reduce the load on your database by sharing connections (which is what RDS Proxy does)?

Comment: My goal is to avoid connection overhead for Lambda invocations

Comment: OK, be aware that RDS Proxy does _not_ solve that problem. Instead, you need to establish a connection and store the connection object in global scope (anything outside the handler function). See the second bullet point in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/best-practices.html#function-code

Comment: If you _do_ want the RDS Proxy behavior, you can run PGBouncer on your Postgres server (or anywhere else that's accessible from the Lambda): https://www.pgbouncer.org/

Comment: You can also use a database edge cache service like PolyScale.ai. The connection speed is lowered due to the connection only being made locally as well as the handshake being cached. PolyScale also supports inbuilt connection pooling. See https://www.polyscale.ai/blog/scaling-data-driven-microservices-globally-with-aws-lambda/